# How to connect to sandboxed server with pytezos?

Tags: sandbox, python

I'm trying to use pytezos with sandboxed tezos server. Pytezos requires the following arguments for connection:

- shell, set to http://localhost:18731/
- key, which I can't figure out

I tried the identity.json created by the sandbox server without success, seems like pytezos really wants a mnemonic:

```
>>> from pytezos import pytezos
>>> pytezos.using(shell='http://localhost:18731', key='/tmp/tezos-node.TyiwsQkx/identity.json')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytezos/tools/docstring.py", line 67, in __call__
    return method(self.class_instance, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytezos/interop.py", line 68, in using
    return self._spawn(shell=shell, key=key)
  File "/home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytezos/client.py", line 27, in _spawn
    key=kwargs.get('key', self.key)
  File "/home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytezos/interop.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.key = Key.from_faucet(key)
  File "/home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytezos/crypto.py", line 214, in from_faucet
    mnemonic=data['mnemonic'],
KeyError: 'mnemonic'
>>>
```

Comment: identity.json is the key your node uses on the peer to peer network for communication, it's not the key to an implicit account.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I couldn't find any command in the manual to generate a faucet account with the sandboxednet, perhaps that would help ?

Comment: This might help https://baking-bad.github.io/pytezos/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accounts are pre-created in Sandboxed mode, this shows how to find the secret keys:

```
$ grep SECRET src/bin_client/tezos-init-sandboxed-client.sh
export BOOTSTRAP1_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk3gUfUPyBSfrS9CCgmCiQsTCHGkviBDusMxDJstFtojtc1zcpsh"
export BOOTSTRAP2_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk39qAm1fiMjgmPkw1EgQYkMzkJezLNewd7PLNHTkr6w9XA2zdfo"
export BOOTSTRAP3_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk4ArLQgBTLWG5FJmnGnT689VKoqhXwmDPBuGx3z4cvwU9MmrPZZ"
export BOOTSTRAP4_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk2uqQB9AY4FvioK2YMdfmyMrer5R8mGFyuaLLFfSRo8EoyNdht3"
export BOOTSTRAP5_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk4QLrcijEffxV31gGdN2HU7UpyJjA8drFoNcmnB28n89YjPNRFm"
export ACTIVATOR_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk31vznjHSSpGExDMHYASz45VZqXN4DPxvsa4hAyY8dHM28cZzp6"
```

Use one of these unencrypted private keys to connect to the sandbox:

```
>>> from pytezos import pytezos
>>> pytezos.using(shell='http://localhost:18731', key='edsk3gUfUPyBSfrS9CCgmCiQsTCHGkviBDusMxDJstFtojtc1zcpsh')
<pytezos.client.PyTezosClient object at 0x7f2c2d78da10>
Properties
.key  # tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
.shell  # http://localhost:18731 ()
```

A pull request is currently open to document this so hopefully it should be there soon : https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/pull/36
EDIT: merged !

Answer (score 2):

Accounts are pre-created in Sandboxed mode, this shows how to find the secret keys:

```
$ grep SECRET src/bin_client/tezos-init-sandboxed-client.sh
export BOOTSTRAP1_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk3gUfUPyBSfrS9CCgmCiQsTCHGkviBDusMxDJstFtojtc1zcpsh"
export BOOTSTRAP2_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk39qAm1fiMjgmPkw1EgQYkMzkJezLNewd7PLNHTkr6w9XA2zdfo"
export BOOTSTRAP3_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk4ArLQgBTLWG5FJmnGnT689VKoqhXwmDPBuGx3z4cvwU9MmrPZZ"
export BOOTSTRAP4_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk2uqQB9AY4FvioK2YMdfmyMrer5R8mGFyuaLLFfSRo8EoyNdht3"
export BOOTSTRAP5_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk4QLrcijEffxV31gGdN2HU7UpyJjA8drFoNcmnB28n89YjPNRFm"
export ACTIVATOR_SECRET="unencrypted:edsk31vznjHSSpGExDMHYASz45VZqXN4DPxvsa4hAyY8dHM28cZzp6"
```

Use one of these unencrypted private keys to connect to the sandbox:

```
>>> from pytezos import pytezos
>>> pytezos.using(shell='http://localhost:18731', key='edsk3gUfUPyBSfrS9CCgmCiQsTCHGkviBDusMxDJstFtojtc1zcpsh')
<pytezos.client.PyTezosClient object at 0x7f2c2d78da10>
Properties
.key  # tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
.shell  # http://localhost:18731 ()
```

A pull request is currently open to document this so hopefully it should be there soon : https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/pull/36

Comment: Well that's also what I thought, but thanks to your previous comment I figured key also accepts an alias ! As such, I'm looking forward to use `key='bootstrap1'` ... however, it looks for keys inside ~/.tezos-client/secret_keys, so if only I could find or make such file for the sandboxed tezos then I could contribute a little note about sandboxed mode in pytezos documentation.

Comment: Apparently I can get the secret key from tezos-init-sandboxed-client.sh and make a secret key file, but that's going to be a bit hacky as such I'll be able to cook an answer but perhaps not a documentable solution.

Comment: Actually we do have quite some options
https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/blob/master/pytezos/interop.py#L46-L56

Comment: Got it, you can pass the unencrypted key to the key argument ... sorry for the noise, contributing an answer and backlinking in this question.
Have a great day !

Comment: Sounds like you have a better answer than mine now, you should post it as an answer to your own question

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have figured if it wasn't for your comment, I thought you knew that I could connect with the alias when you showed me the docs, I tried and it didn't work so I dug in the source code and found the rest... so there's a bit of both of us in the answer !